# How to add condition to method "retry" in kotlin and webflux when api return error data?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux

How to change the parameters with `retry()` in `kotlin` and `webflux` ?

There is a productInfo function, the function parameter is a collection of product ids.

When I input a wrong id in the list collection ids, the upstream interface will only return the wrong id. And get failed.

What I want to achieve is when the upstream interface returns the wrong id. The product info can remove the wrong id and have a second try with the right ids.

I tried to use **retry()** but I don't know how to change the parameters in the second try.

```
    fun productInfo(ids: List<Pair<String, String>>): Flux<ProductItem> {
        return productWebClient
            .get()
            .uri("product/items/${ids.joinToString(";") { "${it.second},${it.first}" }}")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(ProductItem::class.java)
            .onErrorResume {
                logger.error("Fetch products failed." + it.message)
                Mono.empty()
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not `retry()`. I've built a solution making minor assumptions here and there. You can refer to this solution and make changes according to your requirements. I've used recursion here (`productInfo()`). You can replace the recursion call with webclient call if the error occurs only once.

```
fun productInfo(ids: List<Pair<String, String>>): Flux<ProductItem> {
    val idsString = ids.joinToString(";") { "${it.second},${it.first}" }
    return webClient
        .get()
        .uri("product/items/${idsString}")
        .exchange()
        .flatMapMany { response ->
            if (response.statusCode().isError) {
                response.body { clientHttpResponse, _ ->
                    clientHttpResponse.body.cast(String::class.java).collectList()
                        .flatMapMany<ProductItem> { eids ->
                            val ids2 = ids.filter { eids.contains("${it.second},${it.first}") }
                            productInfo(ids2)
                        }
                }
            } else {
                response.bodyToFlux(ProductItem::class.java)
            }
        }
}
```